# Can a 5 year old kid play Legends of Andor?

Tags: kids, legends-of-andor

My daughter loves stories and games. She plays games like [The Magic Labyrinth](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/41916/the-magic-labyrinth) and [Viva Topo!](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/8195/viva-topo) fairly well.

I am thinking about buying [Legends of Andor](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/127398/legends-of-andor) to play with her since it seems to have a nice story line and beautiful components.

Since she does not know how to read yet, I would be doing all the reading, but I don't want to play the game by myself. I'd like her to make her own decisions. Obviously I also want us to be able to beat the game after some effort.

Is she too young for that?

Comment: Not familiar with that game, but you might want to also consider Mice and Mystics http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/124708/mice-and-mystics which sounds similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience with Legends of Andor is that it is primarily a "puzzle".  Time is very limited, and you need to be very strategic about what actions you take in order to succeed.  I don't think most 5 year olds will have this level of analytic thinking yet.  So while your daughter can probably learn the available decisions and be able to choose ones she thinks are reasonable, you'll probably need to tweak the difficulty somewhat in order for her to feel comfortable making her own decisions and not constantly having them lead to failure.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I think I will hold my purchase for some time then.